# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes frequently with light load

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, hardware

I have a Titan Xp and AMD Ryzen 7 with 750W PSU. I would be simply browsing website withs moderate number of tabs open when the screen freezes. I can't do anything except to force power off by holding the power button. What would be the potential problem? I'm using Nvidia driver 390.12 since that's the only one currently working with CUDA and Titan Xp.

When the screen freezes the GPU's LED would be blinking every second. What does this mean? The CPU indicator LED on the motherboard would also light up when the computer freezes.

Comment: If you downloaded CUDA from the official NVIDIA website, CUDA comes bundled with its own NVIDIA driver. Otherwise you probably did something else wrong by installing 390.12, but there is insufficient information in your question to know what that something is.

Comment: What other information can I provide? I installed CUDA following the suggestions from an NVIDIA employee https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1028904/cuda-setup-and-installation/nvidia-driver-not-loading-after-cuda-9-1-installation-with-runfile/post/5234640/#5234640

Comment: From the link in the above comment, it still looks possible that you aren't using the NVIDIA driver that comes bundled with CUDA, and the driver conflict may be causing your system to freeze. What most people do is to download NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit (the latest version is 9.1) from the [official NVIDIA website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).